# How to Delete/modifiy ADF v2 Trigger

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am following the artcile at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers

I have created a Scheduled Trigger to run the pipeline every day.
Where in portal will this show up ?
Also how can i delete or modify this Trigger ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The portal doesnt show much for data factory v2, you have the Monitor & Manage interface that will show you pipeline runs, their activities and stuff, but thats about it, you dont see triggers, datasets, linked services or anything from the portal at the moment (remember its still in preview).

If you have powershell with azure libraries installed, you can modify or delete triggers from it. Just login with

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
```

then select a subscription with

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "your subscription name"
```

To delete the trigger you use the command (fill the "" with your data):

```
Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName "" -DataFactoryName "" -Name ""
```

To modify a trigger you use the same command you used to create a new one:

```
Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName "" -ResourceGroupName "" -Name "" -DefinitionFile C:/(path to json)
```

Hope this helped!

PS: also if you dont remember the name of the trigger, you can get a list of triggers in your data factory with this command:

```
Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName "" -DataFactoryName ""
```

Answer (score 4):

Click the "Manage" button on the left side of the screen, and then click "Triggers" under the "Author" heading.

When you hover over the trigger names you can delete them.

[image: manage ADF triggers]

Answer (score 0):

Super useful, I had renamed a trigger which had actually cloned it so I needed to delete the old one. I had just had a new laptop so I needed to do

```
Install-Module Az

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned --
```

That's a GPO that needs fixing by my organisation

Then I got a little stuck because our resource group name and factory names are very similar. Resource group is on the first page in the middle at the top, factory is the name of the factory